# How to save command-line-arguments in a variable and pass them to the command

Tags: bash, arguments, command-line-arguments

i want to put some arguments into a variable f.e.

```
CFLAGS=-c --sysroot=$sysroot
```

but bash complains that it does not find the file --sysroot... why? How can I put this arguments into the variable and pass them later to the program.

Additionally i would like to do something like:

```
for dir in ${include_dirs[*]};
do
    CFLAGS=$CFLAGS "-I$dir"
done
```

but this does also not work as expected.

EDIT: One solution

```
CFLAGS=("-c" "--sysroot=$sysroot")
```

and in the loop

```
CFLAGS=("${CFLAGS[0]}" "-I$dir")
```

i am wondering if there is maybe a more obvious solution.

Comment: What is the `...` part after the `--sysroot` error?

Comment: The other parts i added to the variable

Comment: You almost had it right the first time. Only 2 changes necessary. `CFLAGS="-c --sysroot==$sysroot"` and in the loop `CFLAGS="$CFLAGS -I$dir"`. Your original post breaks in both places due to spaces while assigning value to variable. By enclosing the space within the quotes, the problem is fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In shell quotes are pretty important so:

```
CFLAGS="-c --sysroot=$sysroot"
```

otherwise BASH interprets it as 2 different argument.

Alternatively you can use arrays to store it:

```
CFLAGS=("-c" "--sysroot=$sysroot")
```

And use them later as:

```
"${CFLAGS[@]}"
```

very important to quote the array expansion.

Comment: If i do CFLAGS="-c --sysroot=$sysroot" execute the loop and call gcc $CFLAGS it outputs unknown argument "-c --sysroot...." and if i do the second suggestion, the loop will not work.

Comment: for more details: [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)